# Make superscript lower for letter with tilde

Tags: superscripts, tilde

Is there any way to have the `t` in my superscript further down?

```
$\widetilde{\boldsymbol{W}}^t$
```

is the code for the second `W^t`, and

```
$\boldsymbol{W}^t$
```

is the code for the first `W^t` in the screen-shot below.

[image]

I would like to have the `t` of both `W`'s exactly at the same height.

Comment: And I assume that the tilde should only span the `W`, as in egreg's answer, and not `W^t`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It comes out right if you load `bm`; this is one of the reasons why `ambsy` has been deprecated and `bm` recommended instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\begin{document}

$\widetilde{\boldsymbol{W}}^t$

$\boldsymbol{W}^t$

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also type the shorter `\bm` instead of `\boldsymbol`.